# Script to download a list with wget in bash

Tags: bash

I have a list of download links (list.txt):

```
https://web.com/file1.zip
https://web.com/file2.zip
https://web.com/file3.zip
```

and so on up to 100...

I'm trying to build a script that will download my files using wget, but the emphasis here is that every time one file is downloaded, the ls command will be executed.
This is what my long script looks like, but I want to shorten it and make it smarter, and instead of manually writing line by line each time, that the script is read line by line and downloaded in order with the execution of the ls command in each download when the first one to turn has finished

```
wget https://web.com/file1.zip && ls ; wget https://web.com/file2.zip && ls ; wget https://web.com/file3.zip && ls ;
```

And so on up to 100

Comment: See [FAQ1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Answer (score 0):

use `forloop` to squash your similar `wget` commands.

```
for i in {1..100}
do
  wget https://web.com/file"$i".zip && ls
done
```

Please be aware of that this is `bash` shell style. You can also write other shell style.

Comment: But I have a list that contains all the links:
https://web.com/file1.zip,
https://web.com/file2.zip,
https://web.com/file3.zip,
So I need that the script read from the list link by link and not manually

Comment: where do the file list store

Comment: in the same folder as the script: cd /desktop/ | ls= script.sh list.txt

Comment: $ while read line; do wget https://"$line" && ls; done < /desktop/list.txt

Comment: I tried this:
"cat list.txt| while read line; do wget $line && ls ; done"
But after the first download it stops and doesn't go any further

Comment: Do you get blocked  by first url because of network reason? Normally it will download in order.  Back download link should not start until front download link have been finished. I try and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for iurl in $(cat list.txt); do
    wget $iurl && ls
done
```